# SSH connection with public RSA key

Tags: ssh, rsa

I have next configuration in our corporative network:

### **Client:** (artur@lothlorien.isd)

**/etc/ssh/ssh_config:**

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

**File permissions:**

```
artur@lothlorien:~$ ls -la ~/.ssh | grep "authorized_keys"
-rw-------  1 artur artur  407 чер  4 10:11 authorized_keys
artur@lothlorien:~$ ls -la ~ | grep ".ssh"
drwx------  2 artur artur   4096 чер  4 10:33 .ssh
```

**More:**

- Server added to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` Content of File
- `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` appended to home directory of
  **isd_programmer@server.isd** user

**/proc/version:**

`Linux version 3.5.0-32-generic (buildd@akateko) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) ) #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:23:04 UTC 2013`

### **Server:** (isd_programmer@server.isd)

- `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` same like on **artur@lothlorien.isd**
- file permissions **600** for `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- directory permissions **700** for `~/.ssh`
- `isd_programmer@server> cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` have public key of **artur@lothlorien.isd**

**/proc/version:**

`Linux version 2.6.38-16-server (buildd@batsu) (gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) ) #67-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 6 18:15:24 UTC 2012`

### **Connection:**

```
artur@lothlorien:~$ ssh isd_programmer@server.isd -v
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server.isd [192.168.1.201] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/artur/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/artur/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/artur/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/artur/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/artur/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/artur/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA bf:55:f2:57:f1:8e:c9:cf:a1:3f:f8:d0:81:6b:d4:7d
debug1: Host 'server.isd' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/artur/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/artur/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/artur/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/artur/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
isd_programmer@server.isd's password:
```

As for me looks like all is configured corect, but why I get prompt to enter password?

**UPD (2013-06-07 07:05:12):** found in `sudo less -500 /var/log/auth.log`:

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /var/www
```

`/var/www` is home directory for **isd_programmer@server.isd**

Comment: Look at the logs on the _server_.

Comment: Look at the logs on the server, and potentially start sshd with debug on the server (/usr/sbin/sshd -DDD) to see what it says. Note that stopping sshd wont kill your already open ssh sessions.

Comment: Updated my question. Got information from `/var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem myself.
`/var/www` has rights:

```
drwxrwxr-x 112 isd_programmer www-data    4096 2013-06-07 10:24 www
```

I can't change permissions since there are more users in **www-data** group who need access to this folder.
But **StrictModes** in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` was set to **yes** *(default)*.
So I changed it to **no** and restarted sshd: `sudo restart ssh`.

Answer (score 2):

Several reasons come to mind:

- Server is configured to not allow key authentication
- Client host is either *not* in hosts.allow or *is* in hosts.deny
- Client user is not a *permitted ssh user*
- Permissions prevent `authorized_keys` from being read (check all parent directories)
- Permissions are too broad for `authorized_keys` (file and all parent directories must not be writable by anyone other than root and *desired user*).
- key doesn't match

There are more reasons, these are the ones that came immediately to mind. Remember this site is about solving problems for *everyone*, not tailoring answers to *your specific server*.

Answer (score 0):

You missed private key in `Client: (artur@lothlorien.isd)`.

In `artur@lothlorien.isd`, place `id_rsa` in `/home/artur/.ssh/` for SSH to work.

Comment: I have this file